# Website made with Bootstrap has problems with layout in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm developing a portfolio website for a web studio. Here it is: http://codenotfound.github.io/coldcrystal/

It works perfectly in Firefox, but in Chrome I've noticed two inconsistencies:

1. Misaligned picture in navbar. I've tried display: inline, it wasn't helpful.
2. Strange border around social icons.

Here's the picture: [problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWRU4.jpg)

I'm no expert in cross-browser compatibility, so some help with these issues will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a read of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - especially the part about including (minimal) code to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution to get work with Chrome:

1.) For the logo you can add the following CSS:

```
#logo {
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

And you have to move the logo `<img id="logo" alt="Website Logo" src="assets/img/logo.png">` into the span `<span class="brand-font navbar-brand" style="display: inline;">` like this:

```
<span class="brand-font navbar-brand">
    <img id="logo" alt="Website Logo" src="assets/img/logo.png">Cold Crystal
</span>
```

You can remove your try `style="display: inline;"`

2.) Simply add `outline:0;` to `.social-icons i` to remove the line around the social icons.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian! You were most helpful. My problem is solved.